# Plotting a 2D vector field with a 3D matrix quiver -MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, plot

I am having real trouble with vectors/matrices etc. in matlab.

I have a 3D vector nxmx2 where n is my x-coordinate, m is my y-coordinate and for each (x,y) there are two z values, the first being my velocity in the x-direction, and the second being my velocity in the y-direction.

How do I plot these velocity functions on a x-y graph? I have been trying with things like:

```
quiver(A)
quiver(A,A,A(:,:,1),A(:,:,2))
```

But can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: What about `quiver(A(:,:,1),A(:,:,2))`?

Comment: That seems to have worked, perfect, thank you

Comment: @Naveh I guess you can post this as an answer so that Andrew can accept it :)

Comment: Great! I'll write it up for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to use [`quiver`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver.html) for the input you describe is

```
quiver(A(:,:,1), A(:,:,2));
```

If you want the axes of the plot to have equal-spaced values different than `1,2,...` you should use [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) to generate them, as shown in the examples in the `quiver` documentation.